# Hibernate does not save data into DB?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have a form where i input details, but when i click on save it does not get saved in the database... though the table does get created.

**My Contact POJO**

```
package your.intermedix.domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="USER")

public class Contact implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String lastname;
    private String designation;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="DESIGNATION")
    public String getDesignation(){
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(String designation){
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    public String getLastname(){
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname){
        this.lastname= lastname;
    }

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String toString()
    {
        return "designation = '" + designation + "',email='"+ email +"', lastname='"+ lastname +"', name = '" + name + "'";
    }

}
```

My Application-Context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<!-- Turn on AspectJ @Configurable support -->

<context:spring-configured />
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
<context:component-scan base-package="your.intermedix"/>
<context:annotation-config/>
 <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>

  <!-- a PlatformTransactionManager is still required -->
  <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <!-- (this dependency is defined somewhere else) -->
  <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
  </bean>


<!-- Turn on @Autowired, @PostConstruct etc support -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />


    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>your.intermedix.domain.Contact</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/spring"/>
        <property name="username" value="monty"/>
        <property name="password" value="indian"/>
    </bean>   
</beans>
```

I am not getting any sort of error.... in the console.

Updated code..

```
package your.intermedix.services;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import your.intermedix.domain.Contact;
import your.intermedix.services.IContact;

@Service
public class ContactSerImpl implements IContact {

    private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

        public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
            this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }
            @Transactional
        public void saveContact(Contact contact) {
            System.out.println("Hello Guru contact");
            System.out.println(contact);
            hibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdate(contact);
        }

        public void hello() {
            System.out.println("Hello Guru");
        }
}
```

My Service class where i the print statements work

Comment: Can you give us the save code ? Your method where you create your new object and save it.

Comment: You've shown us your entity & configuration, but you haven't shown us the relevant part. That is, code handling your form.

Comment: Have you defined a transaction ?

Comment: Where should i define it... and why?

Comment: I am also assuming that your println `Hello Guru` is printed out? I would also recommend using log4j or another logging system and logging the hibernate classes to see what is going on.

Comment: Can you show the code where you call ContactSerImpl??

Comment: This method does get called from my front end layer.

Answer (score 5):

You need a running transaction. [Spring transaction management](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html) is the way to go if using `HibernateTemplate`. Read the documentation. It's too long to include in an answer, but here is in short:

- you need to define a transaction manager as a spring bean
- you need `<tx:annotation-driven />`
- you need to annotate your transactional methods with `@Transactional`

Comment: I have updated my main post, where i have added Transaction Manager and other stuffs. Still the object does not get persist in the DB.

Comment: @theJava - you'd need a HibernateTransactionManager

Comment: <bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory" />
</bean> I updated with this and does not work either

Comment: @thejava did you update the manager id in tx annotation driven

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the Spring-Hibernate framework, but often when data is not written it menas it is not [flushed](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.1.4/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate/HibernateAccessor.html#setFlushMode%28int%29) to the databackend. What gives you

```
System.err.println(hibernateTemplate.getFlushMode());
```

Comment: This statement does not get called itself.